# Ruby On Rails FullCalendar Events drag and drop not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, fullcalendar

I'm working on a new ruby on rails app and I'm using FullCalendar for calendar management. I have a series of outside events called activities and I want to be able to update the columns `starts_at` and `ends_at` when I drag them and drop them into the Calendar. I'm block here and when I drop the activity it doesn't update my values.

Here is my activities/index.html.slim

```
ul#external-events
 -@activities.each do |activity|
   li.fc-event data-ac-id="#{activity.id}"
    =activity.title

#calendar_now
```

My CoffeeScript file

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#calendar_now').fullCalendar
    droppable: true,
    editable: true,
    header:
      left: '',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    eventsSources: '/activities',
    eventDrop: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) ->
      $.ajax
        url: '/activities/update_activities'
        type: 'post'
        data: id: event.id
        dataType: 'json'
        success: (response) ->
          console.log 'response'
    drop: (date) ->
      id_ac = $(this).data('ac')
      $.ajax
        url: '/activities/update_activities'
        type: 'post'
        data: start: date, id: id_ac
        dataType: 'json'
        success: (response) ->
          console.log 'response'
      $(this).remove();
```

My Activities controller

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = Activity.where(user_id: current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: ([@activities]) }
    end
  end

  def update_activities
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    @activity.starts_at = params[:start]
    @activity.save

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used an older version of FullCalendar in my application so this may not be absolutely correct however here are some suggestions:

1. The `update_activities` controller action should be called `update` and should be a `put` not a `post`.
2. You are updating the activity not creating a new one so `type: 'post'` should be `type: 'put'`.
3. It looks like your `drop: (date) ->` function is never called.
4. If you are using the latest version of FullCalendar then `eventDrop: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) ->` function looks wrong. The [current documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Duration/) has the signature as `function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) { }`. And the delta is a [duration](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Duration/) object.
5. Your data is missing the event start so `data: id: event.id` should be `data: id: event.id start: event.start`

Comment: Thanks for your answer JosephL :) I made the changes but I think 3) is the main issue since when I drop the activity I get in my console

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solution**

It works perfectly this way. Thanks to JosephL.

My updated files

coffeescript file

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#calendar_now').fullCalendar
    droppable: true,
    editable: true,
    header:
      left: '',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    eventSources: [{
      url: '/activities',
    }],
    eventDrop: (event, delta) ->
      $.ajax
        url: '/activities/update'
        type: 'put'
        data: id_ac_data: event.id, start: event.start.format()
        dataType: 'json'
        success: (response) ->
          console.log 'response'
    drop: (start) ->
      id_ac = $('#ac_id').data('ac')
      $.ajax
        url: '/activities/update'
        data:
          start: start.format()
          id_ac_data: id_ac
        type: 'put'
        dataType: 'json'
        success: (response) ->
          console.log 'response'
      $(this).remove();
```

in activities index controller

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.html # index.html.erb
 format.json { render json: @activities }
end
```

the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefined comes from the fact I was rendering json in an array... but @activities was already an array

Anyway thanks :)